# I get an error message immediately after I create a Navigation Drawer activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

As soon as my Navigation Drawer Activity is created, the values-v23.xml file opens containing this code:

?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground

```
    <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
</style>
<style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>

    <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
</style>
<!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base.xml -->
<eat-comment/>
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored"/>
```

It cannot resolve "android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse" and 
"android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored".

I also get this error message in the stack trace:

Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'. 
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Vanessa Anthony\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Any help on the solution to this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Android SDK Manager download the latest (revision 23) **Android SDK Build-tools** and update the *Android SDK Platform-tools* and *Android SDK Tools*.